# PHP Login with different user level

Tags: php

Im creating a different user level. In my table username there is a admin and library. but it seems it always directs me to this php page thankyou for the answers.

```
<?php session_start();

$username="root";
$password="yujiro14";
$hostname = "localhost";

$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die ("Could not connect to database");

$selected = mysql_select_db("login", $dbhandle);

$myusername = $_POST['user'];
$mypassword = $_POST['pass'];

$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);

$query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username='$myusername' and Password='$mypassword'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

if($rows==1){
if ($rows['Username'] == "admin") {
header("location: login_success.php"); //User1 

}
else
if ($rows['Username'] == "Library") {
header("location: library.php"); //User2 


} 
}
mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: **WARNING:** You're using a deprecated database API. Consider using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) and binding your parameters.

Comment: You should `die;` or `exit;` after you send a `header('Location: ...);` to stop further code execution. Are you getting any errors on screen? Are the usernames case sensitive? What page does it always direct you to? I seems like you're storing plain-text passwords. Maybe you should see: http://plaintextoffenders.com/

Answer (score 0):

As said before, try to use PDO or prepared MySQLi. But, regarding your issue:

How you're handling the data in your `login_success.php` page, for example?

Probably you wrote something like:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['admin'])){
     header("Location:login.php"); 
}
```

If I'm right, you missed the session creating in your sample above. So, try:

```
if ($rows['Username'] == "admin") {
    $_SESSION['admin'] = $rows['Username']; <-- add something like this
    header("location: login_success.php"); //User1 
}
```